# Erros while installing connecting to 2 different databases using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to connect to two different databases using EF6, the strange part is I don't have any issue if I only connect to one of the database. The moment I setup EF for another database, I run into errors. Here's a screenshot of the errors, any idea why it would happen or how to debug this error?

[image]

Comment: can anyone provide guidance on what is the cause of this error or how to debug?

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, the class Variant is present in two namespaces, it could be that you have two classes with the same name.